# How to call one asmx from another asmx

Tags: c#

I'm in a C#-SAP project integration that involves ICI communication and one contact center.

For long as we made a TRACE for the SAP communications, we detect that SAP makes several calls to web services methods with several namespaces. But because SAP CRM configures only one endpoint in the external HTTP connections, we need to catch the SOAPAction and then call the proper web service.

Is this possible?
How to catch the SOAPAction header and then redirects the call to the proper web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no need of redirect. Just to learn how to use the "RequestNamespace" and "ResponseNamespace" in the "SoapDocumentMethod"

Comment: Just a friendly comment: this answer should be expanded to bring value to the community.